# Prove that the polynomial $x^nf(1/x)$ with reverted coefficients is also irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

If $a_0+a_1 x+  \ldots + a_ n x^ n$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ then $a_n+ a_{n-1} x +\ldots+a_0x^{n}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: In such cases uses Gauss's lemma. Choose a prime to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ with $\deg g=k$, $\deg h=m$. Then the other polynomial is $x^nf(1/x)$ and we have $x^nf(1/x)=x^kg(1/x)\cdot x^mh(1/x)$.